# Compatibility of tslib_eidtools for typo3 7

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x

I am trying to make a pi base extension compatible with typo3 7.6.4. But I am unable to make the compatible version of the following code

```
$this->feUserObj = tslib_eidtools::initFeUser();                
// Connect to database:         
tslib_eidtools::connectDB();
```

It throws the error : Class tslib_eidtools not found. How can i convert the tslib_eidtools class, so that it gets compatible with typo3 7?

Answer (score 0):

In Core File of TYPO3 7.6 LTS the database connection establishing code is located in core/Classes/Database/DatabaseConnection.php. You don't have to create the object of this class.

**You could get the DB Object and Connection Parameters from the TYPO3 Globals Constant $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']. Refer [Click Here](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_database_1_1_database_connection.html)**

You could able to write the custom mysql queries using this global object.

**Example :**

```
$results = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows (
                                         $select_fields, 
                                         $from_table, 
                                         $where_clause, 
                                         $groupBy= '', 
                                         $orderBy= '', 
                                         $limit= '', 
                                         $uidIndexField= '' );
```

TYPO3 "database wrapper" class (new in 3.6.0) This class contains

- abstraction functions for executing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT
  queries ("Query execution"; These are REQUIRED for all future
  connectivity to the database, thus ensuring DBAL compliance!)
- functions for building SQL queries (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT)
  ("Query building"); These are transitional functions for building SQL
  queries in a more automated way. Use these to build queries instead
  of doing it manually in your code!
- mysqli wrapper functions; These are transitional functions. By a
  simple search/replace you should be able to substitute all mysql*()
  calls with       $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql*() and your application
  will work out of       the box. YOU CANNOT (legally) use any mysqli
  functions not found as      wrapper functions in this class! See the
  Project Coding Guidelines       (doc_core_cgl) for more instructions
  on best-practise

Also this connect() method you wont need to use in most of the cases from TYPO3 6.2